# WPF Height/Width

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, height, width

In a custom WPF control I would like to set the width of the control to be a function of the Height.  For example:  `Width = Height / 3 * x;`

What would be the best way to accomplish this so that the control resizes (and initially sizes) correctly and fluidly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could bind `Width` to `ActualHeight`, and use [converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx#data_conversion) to apply custom function. E.g. the following code makes Button always squared:

```
<Button Width="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
```

Hope this helps,

Cheers, Anvaka.